# <% %> <--What is this called? How do I write C# code in it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

<strike>I am using asp.net mvc and I have a table with value.  When the customer paid value = 0. I want it to display No payment in the cell. When it Customer paid = 1. I want it to display. Pending. When it = 2 i want it to display Paid.</strike>

I am attempting to write an inline code block to display payment status based on the value of the `Paid` property on my `Customer` class. If the value is "0", I need to display an empty cell. If the value is "1" I need to print "Pending" into the cell, and if the value is "2" I need to print "Paid".

I have the following already, but I am not sure how to get the value into the cell.

```
<%foreach (var Customer in CustomerList)  {%>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="<%= Customer.ThirdPartyCustomerId %>" /></td>
    <td><%=Customer.FirstName%></td>
    <td><%= if(Customer.Paid==0)
            {
                Customer.Paid== "No Payment";
            };%>
    </td>        
 </tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Those characters define an inline code block

Comment: I've done a large edit on the question, hopefully it's an improvement and sticks to the original. This was to combat the slew of close votes mounting as people were judging it "not a real question".

Comment: You should post this as a new question since the context has changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no ASPX expert, but wouldn't this work?

```
<td>
    <% if(Customer.Paid==0) { %>No payment<% } %>
    <% else if(Customer.Paid==1) { %>Pending<% } %>
    <% else { %>Paid<% } %>
</td>
```

or, if you want it in one line

```
<td>
    <%= Customer.Paid == 0 ? "No payment" : (Customer.Paid == 1 ? "Pending" : "Payed") %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

They're called code delimiters.

`<%=Customer.FirstName%>` outputs a value

```
<%= if(Customer.Paid==0)
            {
                Customer.Paid== "No Payment";
};%>
```

Above, you aren't outputting a value, so no `=` sign is required.

Comment: do you need the semi colon at the end?

Comment: @user1392576: Did you take a peek at my answer below?